# Dar valores de un array multidimensoional a otro array

Tags: php

Tengo esta función que recibe `$piezas`, estas son una `$matriz[][]` que al llamarla devuelve:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 [3] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 [2] => 4 [3] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 4 [2] => 0 [3] => 3 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 4 [3] => 3 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 [3] => 5 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 5 [2] => 2 [3] => 4 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 5 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 4 ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 [2] => 2 [3] => 4 ) [12] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 ) [13] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 2 [3] => 0 ) [14] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 5 [3] => 2 ) [15] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 0 [3] => 4 ) )
```

La función es la siguiente:

```
function bordes($piezas){
   
    global $borde;

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($piezas); $i++) {

        $contador = 0;
        //print_r($piezas[$i]);
    
        for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){
           
            if($piezas[$i][$j] == 0){

                $contador++;
                
                if($contador == 2){
                    
                    $borde[$i] = $piezas[$i];
           
                    //print_r($borde[$i]);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($borde); $i++) {
        print_r($borde[$i]);
    }
}
```

Lo que hace es ver el numero de piezas con `sizeOf(16 piezas)`, después compara los valores de cada pieza `[$j]` y si es cero, el `contador++`. Si alguna pieza tiene dos ceros, es decir, `contador == 2`, querría guardarla en una variable nueva que tengo declarada fuera como `$borde = array(array())`. Esto es lo que me falla, no consigo darle a `$borde` el valor de la `pieza[$i]` correspondiente, es decir, la que tiene dos ceros.

Ahora mismo lo que me devuelve es esto:

```
Array ( )
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\pruebaPuzzle\index.php on line 79
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 )
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\pruebaPuzzle\index.php on line 79
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 4 [3] => 3 )
```

Ayuda por favor :´(

Comment: Falla al recorrer el arreglo `$borde` para mostrar sus valores por pantalla (al final de la función), porque solo están definidas las llaves 2, 4, 5 y 6 (que son las piezas que tienen dos ceros) y tu estás iterando de 0 a 3 (la llave 0, 1 y 3 no están definidas y por eso te muestra la notificación). Utiliza un `foreach` para iterar o has un `var_dump($borde)` (en lugar de iterar con un `for`) y te vas a dar cuenta de porque falla.

Comment: @nachospiu lo entiendo, pero y como lo arreglo?

Comment: Agregué una respuesta para que veas como podríás mostrar los elementos de arreglo `$borde`, cualquier duda me consultas. No hay una única solución, lo podrías solucionar de diferentes maneras, dependiendo del resultado que quieras lograr.

Comment: @nachospiu lo que quiero hacer es guardar esas piezas en borde para poder eliminarlas luego del primer array piezas, pero ni con unset ni con array_diff lo consigo, no se si es por el error que me has comentado o porque, sabrias como hacerlo? muchas gracias

Comment: Si en el bucle `foreach` en lugar de hacer el `print_r($value);` haces `unset($piezas[$key]);` va a eliminar las piezas del parámetro $piezas (pero solo dentro de la función, si quieres que ya no estén en el arreglo original tienes que pasar el parámetro `$piezas` por referencia, con `&`).

Comment: Daniel pudiste resolverlo? Si mi respuesta te sirvió no olvides seleccionarla, así tu pregunta que marcada como respondida.

Answer (score 0):

Como mencioné en los comentarios: Falla al recorrer el arreglo `$borde` para mostrar sus valores por pantalla (al final de la función), porque solo están definidas las llaves 2, 4, 5 y 6 (que son las piezas que tienen dos ceros) y tu estás iterando de 0 a 3 (la llave 0, 1 y 3 no están definidas y por eso te muestra la notificación). Utiliza un `foreach` para iterar o has un `var_dump($borde);` (en lugar de iterar con un `for`) y te vas a dar cuenta de porque falla.

Una opción es reemplazar el `for` donde muestras por pantalla las piezas que tiene dos ceros, por un `foreach`:

```
foreach($borde as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
```

Sino puedes utilizar un `var_dump($borde);` (en lugar del `for`), depende de como quieras mostrar dicho arreglo.

Este es el contenido del arreglo `$borde` en función de los datos de ejemplo de la pregunta (arreglo `$piezas`):

```
array ( 2 => array ( 0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 0 ), 
        4 => array ( 0 => 0, 1 => 0, 2 => 4, 3 => 3 ), 
        5 => array ( 0 => 0, 1 => 0, 2 => 1, 3 => 1 ), 
        6 => array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 4, 2 => 0, 3 => 0 ))
```

Una opción para eliminar las piezas con dos ceros es especificar en la declaración de la función que el parámetro `$piezas` pasa por referencia:

```
$borde = array();

function bordes(& $piezas) {

    global $borde;

    foreach($piezas as $key => $pieza) {
        $contador = 0;

        foreach($pieza as $valor) {
            if($valor == 0) {
                $contador++;

                if($contador == 2) {
                    $borde[$key] = $pieza;
                    unset($piezas[$key]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$piezas = Array ( 0 => Array ( 0 =>  2,  1 =>  5,  2 =>  4,  3 =>  0 ),  1 => Array ( 0 =>  2,  1 =>  1,  2 =>  4,  3 =>  2 ),  2 => Array ( 0 =>  0,  1 =>  1,  2 =>  1,  3 =>  0 ),  3 => Array ( 0 =>  4,  1 =>  4,  2 =>  0,  3 =>  3 ),  4 => Array ( 0 =>  0,  1 =>  0,  2 =>  4,  3 =>  3 ),  5 => Array ( 0 =>  0,  1 =>  0,  2 =>  1,  3 =>  1 ),  6 => Array ( 0 =>  1,  1 =>  4,  2 =>  0,  3 =>  0 ),  7 => Array ( 0 =>  4,  1 =>  4,  2 =>  3,  3 =>  5 ),  8 => Array ( 0 =>  5,  1 =>  5,  2 =>  2,  3 =>  4 ),  9 => Array ( 0 =>  1,  1 =>  1,  2 =>  0,  3 =>  5 ),  10 => Array ( 0 =>  4,  1 =>  1,  2 =>  0,  3 =>  4 ),  11 => Array ( 0 =>  1,  1 =>  0,  2 =>  2,  3 =>  4 ),  12 => Array ( 0 =>  3,  1 =>  5,  2 =>  1,  3 =>  2 ),  13 => Array ( 0 =>  1,  1 =>  4,  2 =>  2,  3 =>  0 ),  14 => Array ( 0 =>  0,  1 =>  1,  2 =>  5,  3 =>  2 ), 15 => Array ( 0 =>  1,  1 =>  5,  2 =>  0,  3 =>  4 ) );

bordes($piezas);
```